# Find matching word in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, for-loop

I'm facing a problem to solve this issue. I'm having a string variable, for an example

```
              string text="ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
```

I need to search a string value like 'BC' into above string and find the position where "BC" occur. i.e if we search "BC" in to that string variable it will bring the output as 1,6

```
              0   1   2   3  4    5   6   7   8   9   10  11 12   13
            -------------------------------------------------------
            | A | B | C | D | , | A | B | C | D | , | A | D | C | S |
            -------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is we cant use built in string class methods `contains()`, `lastIndexOf()`. can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Assuming this is homework? If so, then tag it as such please. Also, [what have you tried yourself?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @J.Steen Now I changed to homework. I tried with nested for loop, but it worked only for single character searching.

Comment: Show us some of your work. We prefer to see an effort at solving issues on your own first and then asking questions about specific problems you run into. =)

Comment: To the people answering - while I certainly don't begrudge you your right to post as many answers as you like, at whatever level you like, isn't the point of homework to learn by doing?

Comment: @Harry180 I've tried that in a different way.but i couldnt get the desire result.

Comment: @harry180 I can appreciate your comment on me.I'm in the process of learning c#. that why i posted this question, I tried that for last 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is we cant use built in string class methods
>   'contains()','lastIndexOf()'. can anyone help me to do this?

Then you can built your own. I assume that even `Substring` is forbidden.

```
string text="ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
string whatToFind = "BC";

List<int> result = new List<int>();
for(int index=0; index < text.Length; index++)
{
    if(index + whatToFind.Length > text.Length)
        break;
    bool matches = true;
    for(int index2=0; index2<whatToFind.Length; index2++)
    {
        matches = text[index+index2] == whatToFind[index2];
        if(!matches)
            break;
    }
    if(matches)
        result.Add(index);
}
```

Here's the running code: http://ideone.com/s7ej3

Answer (score 0):

This should work out for you:

```
string text="ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
var seekindex = 0;
var positions = new List<int>();
while( seekindex < text.Length ){
  var index = text.IndexOf( "BC", seekindex);
  if( index > -1){
    positions.Add(index);
    seekindex = index + 1;
  }else{
    break;
  }
}
```

This uses the `IndexOf` method with a startindex to make sure that we continue searhing from our previous hit location the next time, and untill `IndexOf` returns -1 indication no more hits.

`positions` will contain the indexes at the end, and the result is actually 1,6,10 and not 1,6 ;)

**EDIT**

Just realized he could not use `IndexOf`. Trying again :)

```
string text="ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
var positions = new List<int>();
for( int i = 0; i < text.Length-1; i++ ){
  if( text[i] == 'B' && text[i+1] == 'C' ){
    positions.Add(i);
  }
}
```

It might seem like a preformance problem here since the if sentence checks both the current, and the next char, and therefore checking  all chars twice.

But in fact it wont. Because of the AND (&&) in between, if `text[i]` is not B, it will not perform the second check since it knows that the if will fail anyway.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen thanks for your prompt answer. but we cant use IndexOf() method, apologies I'vent mentioned earlier

Comment: Whoops, did not read that part of the question. But it gets so much nastier without it ;)

Comment: @ArooranS - Try it now instead :)

Comment: @Øyvind if in case if we pass searching text as a parameter, then it couldnt be a fixed length. is there is any way to implemented using nested loop?

Comment: Why do you need to use nested loops? No reason to make it more complicated than it needs to right? What is the problem you have with my solution? If you let me know, we can find a solution for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
            int location;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                if (text[i] == 'B')
                    if (text[i + 1] == 'C')
                    {
                        location = i;
                        i++;
                    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
List<int> locations = new List<int>();
string text = "ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
                for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                    if (text[i] == 'B')
                        if (text[i + 1] == 'C')
                        {
                            location.Add(i);
                            i++;
                        }
```

Comment: change `int location` to `List<int> locations = new List<int>();` and then change `location = i;` to `locations.Add(i);` then you will add all index which are correct. Now you will get only last one

Comment: yes i know that but he could output it right away and i think he has already someway of storing the locations if not and this is probably homework and he should think a little more or at least figure it a away to store ints so he can become a better programmer

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't use regural expression in your homework. The best solution is think about your string as char array. Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Rolling your own version of `IndexOf` is not hard (as per the answers you've already received), and since it's homework, you can probably get away with it.

However, as you can probably imagine, a simple `for` loop is not the most efficient way to do it. String searching is an important topic, and although you won't probably need to implement it outside of homework ever again, you can [read about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) for your own edification.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a perfectly working example to your requirements, but is also nice and slow and also has a big memory footprint:

```
string text = "ABCD,ABCDABCD,ADCDS";
string whatToFind = "BC";

string delim = "";    

for(int index=0; index < text.Length; index++)
{
    if(index + whatToFind.Length > text.Length)
        break;

    if(text.SubString(index, whatToFind.Length) == whatToFind)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(delim + index.ToString())
        delim = ",";
    }
}
```

I leave it to the reader as an exercise to improve the performance and memory usage. It's more useful to understand where and why this is slow than to achieve a faster answer.